# Making a form that marks end of screen

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Sorry for the vague title but I wasn't sure how to describe my wish/problem.

A while ago I made a sidebar with a few widgets that I can add.

It displays time, date, windows volume, how many % my phone is charged (once connected), some equalizer bars and song + artist currently playing on Spotify.

At the moment the bar is on the right hand side of my main monitor. What I want is to put it on the left side of my secondary monitor. (not quite relevant)

I would like this sidebar to act as if its the end of the screen.
So if I would maximize an application it would end at the border of my sidebar.

I made a little image to illustrate the goal.
Red is the sidebar and blue is a random application.

[image: Example]

Does anyone know if and how this can be achieved?
If anything else is unclear let me know :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WpfAppBar](https://github.com/PhilipRieck/WpfAppBar) to add such functionality